# using legend() in Sweave: is this a bug?

Tags: r, sweave

Right now I am learning sweave to write a package vignette. I am using traditional R graphics. Strangely a legend that I added to a highlevel plot that works fine otherwise does not work when I Sweave the file. Here is a minimal example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \begin{document}
 <<fig=TRUE>>=
 plot(0.5, 0.5, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1))
 legend("bottomright", c("data", "summary", "curve", "conf. region"), 
      pch = c(2,1,NA,NA), lwd = c(NA,NA, 2,1))
 @
 \end{document}
```

The R code produces (when run R version 2.15) a single point and a legend consisting of two points, and two different types of lines:
[image: correct legend]

In sweave the legend fails to be produced, I just see an empty box:
[image: no legend]

Is this a sweave bug, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: I guess this should be reported to R core: https://bugs.r-project.org/

Comment: Ok! I will submit this as a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The problem

This does appear to be a bug, but it's a problem with `pdf()` and not with `Sweave()` itself.

To see what I mean, try this call to `pdf()`. It produces the same defective plot displayed above:

```
pdf("pdfPlot.pdf")
    plot(0.5, 0.5, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1))
    legend("bottomright", c("data", "summary", "curve", "conf. region"), 
         pch = c(2,1,NA,NA), lwd = c(NA,NA, 2,1))
dev.off()
```

By contrast, `cairo_pdf()` produces a plot that looks just fine:

```
cairo_pdf("cairo_pdfPlot.pdf")
    plot(0.5, 0.5, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1))
    legend("bottomright", c("data", "summary", "curve", "conf. region"), 
         pch = c(2,1,NA,NA), lwd = c(NA,NA, 2,1))
dev.off()
```

### Solution 1: Use knitr.

If you are willing to make the switch to `knitr`, fixing this is easy. Just add `dev="cairo_pdf"`  to your code chunk header (and, if you like, drop the `fig=TRUE`), like this:

```
<<dev="cairo_pdf">>=
...
...
@
```

Processing the code is then as simple as doing `library(knitr); knit("myScript.Rnw")` in place of your current call to `Sweave("myScript.Rnw")`

### Solution 2: Construct your own call to \includegraphics{}.

If you must stick with `Sweave()`, doing something like this will get you around the problem:

```
<<results=tex, term=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
cairo_pdf("myPlot.pdf", width=5)
    plot(0.5, 0.5, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1))
    legend("bottomright", c("data", "summary", "curve", "conf. region"),
         pch = c(2,1,NA,NA), lwd = c(NA,NA, 2,1))
dev.off()
cat("\\includegraphics{myPlot.pdf}\n\n")
@
```

Comment: in `knitr`, you do not need `fig=TRUE`; figures will always produced unless you suppress them

Comment: @Yihui -- Yet another nice design decision. Thanks. (I've revised the knitr-bound code block to make note of that difference.)

Comment: To be more accurate: it's a bug (oops, pdf is Ripley-territory, so better call it "possible infelicity") with use of NA in pch and lwd. Try non-NA, it works, but I could not find a solution that gives the required display.